# Test MASM programs online

Tags: assembly, x86, ide, masm

I'm trying to find a way to test assembly language programs using MASM syntax online, but I haven't yet found any way to do this.
Are there any online tools that will make it possible to test MASM programs online (like *jsfiddle* or *ideone*, but for MASM)?

Comment: It appears that http://ideone.com makes it possible to run assembly language programs online, using either Intel syntax or AT&T syntax. I'm not sure whether NASM syntax will work here, though.

Answer (score 4):

As of earlier today, you can, at [tryitonline.net](https://tio.run/##XY1LDoJAEETX06doWSOB6MJ4Am/A0vTQnajpYQzT@Dn9iMKCWKuXVOUVpSTB63t7e1IKOVdMRhBHu4@G7LE4iWossY2D8qYAqLrIAudkNNgRXIgPFHqVuF/YT9yAUyGUbuJZtZT8LXfgrr3hL4f6snI0K0f9t5KecX7N@QM). Although technically that's JWasm and not Masm, JWasm is an open source assembly compiler that functions identically to Masm.

Note, however, that TIO is powered by Linux, so Windows libraries are unavailable, and system calls are done differently.